# What is the difference that explains different results of different ways to assign values in a command-line?

Tags: bash, command-line, environment-variables

What is the difference that explains the different results of these commands?

1. `a=2 echo $a`
2. `set a=2 echo $a`
3. `a=2; echo $a`
4. `set a=2; echo $a`

Answer (score 7):

1. `a=2 echo $a`

   **Result:** *output a blank line*

   **Reason:** Bash provides a subset of its variables (the [environment](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html)) to every program you call with it (you can specify which with the [`export`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html#sect_03_02_03) builtin). Prefixing a command with e.g. `a=2` tells bash to add `$a` (with value `2`) to the environment, but

   - only for that particular program, and
   - not to the set of variables used by `bash` itself.

   So, if `echo` were a program (it's [actually a builtin](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_01.html#sect_08_01_02)), it would receive `$a` along with the other environment variables ... but `echo` **doesn't care** about environment variables - it just spits back the arguments you give it. Since `$a` isn't defined as a variable in `bash` itself, your command is equivalent to a bare `echo`, which emits a newline character, giving you a blank line.

1. `set a=2 echo $a`

   **Result:** *no output*

   **Reason:** This isn't doing what you think it is - in fact, the `echo` command isn't called at all. When [`set`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) is called without options, it sets the [positional parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html) to the arguments you give it, in order. You can see this with a couple of extra commands:

   ```
   $ set a=2 echo $a
   $ echo $1
   a=2
   $ echo $2
   echo
   ```

   ... and `echo $3` gives a blank line, because you tried to set `$3` to `$a`, which doesn't exist.

1. `a=2; echo $a`

   **Result:** *output `2` (at last!)*

   **Reason:** This is the correct way to get what you want: you set the variable `$a` to `2`, and then you called `echo` with `$a` as an argument.

1. `set a=2; echo $a`

   **Result:**

   - If `$a` is already set to `2`: *output `2`*
   - If `$a` is not set: *output a blank line*

   **Reason:** Hopefully you can work this out for yourself, given the explanations above.